# Unhide rows within a range one by one using a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a command button to unhide rows one by one in a range. When I use debug it is working correctly but in reality what happens is it unhides all rows at once, not just in this range but in the 8 different ranges I have set up.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("A18:G41")
  
  
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 18
    For i = 18 To 41
   Do
        If Rows(i).Hidden = True Then
        Rows(i).Hidden = False
        Exit Do
        ElseIf Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
        i = i + 1
        Else
    End If
    Loop Until i = 41
    
 If i = 41 Then
 MsgBox "There are no more rows for hourly labor remaining"
 Else
 End If
    Cancel = True
    
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation a bit and describe which rows you are attempting to hide.

Comment: You do this `Set rng = Range("A18:G41")` but then do nothing with `rng`?  Also it's bad practice to modify a `For...Next` loop counter inside the loop.  Not sure you need that inner `Do` loop?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be easier to manage:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UnhideNextRow Range("B4:F10")          'fixed range
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    UnhideNextRow Me.ListObjects("MyTable3").DataBodyRange  'list object range
End Sub

'loop over rows in `rng` and unhide the first hidden one
'  Show message if no more rows
Sub UnhideNextRow(rng As Range)
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If rw.Hidden Then
            rw.Hidden = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rw
    MsgBox "no more rows to unhide!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Interestingly, using `For Each rw In rng.Columns(1).Rows`, making `rw` one cell, will also work, while using `For Each rw In rng.Columns(1).Cells` will fail.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I agree - that's odd...